# Logging the path where request was received in restify

Tags: node.js, restify, bunyan

I am using bunyan to log restify activity.

My restify file looks something like this:

```
var restify = require('restify')
var bunyan = require('bunyan')

log = bunyan.createLogger({
    name: 'Restify_Activity_logs',
    level: 'info',
    stream: process.stdout,
    serializers: bunyan.stdSerializers
})

var server = restify.createServer({
  log: log,
  name: 'SomeName'
});

server.pre(function(req,res,next){
  log.info({req:req}, 'start');
   return next();
});

server.on('after', restify.auditLogger({log:log}));
```

The above is very standard code, however it fails to log the routes for which the request came in. 
What I mean is it does not log all the various routes that I have like

```
/users/:id/
/cars/:model/year/:year
```

I would like to see the above logged and not just the final URL. Any clues as to what parameters I am missing here?